# nginx: [warn] could not build optimal variables_hash, you should increase either variables_hash_max_size: 1024 or variables_hash_bucket_size: 64

Tags: nginx

I can't set the Nginx hash tables correctly.

I keep getting this warning:

> nginx: [warn] could not build optimal variables_hash, you should
> increase either variables_hash_max_size: 1024 or
> variables_hash_bucket_size: 64; ignoring variables_hash_bucket_size

I have increased the values several times by multiplying them by two but it does not work.

```
map_hash_max_size 4096;
map_hash_bucket_size 256;
```

How to correct this problem?

**Here is my server configuration:**

- Debian 11
- Nginx-extras 1.18.0
- Intel Core i9-9900K (8 Cores and 16 Threads)
- 128GB RAM DDR4

**Here is the Nginx config file:**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

### global ###
server_tokens off;
keepalive_requests 100;

### tcp ###
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
sendfile on;

### timeouts ###
reset_timedout_connection on;
client_body_timeout 12;
client_header_timeout 12;
keepalive_timeout 15;
send_timeout 10;

### buffers ###
types_hash_max_size 4096;
server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
map_hash_max_size 4096;
map_hash_bucket_size 256;
client_max_body_size 20M;
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

### ssl ###
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_certificate /etc/cloudflare/cloudflare.com.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/cloudflare/cloudflare.com.key;

### LIMIT CONNEXION ###
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=reqlimit:100m rate=10r/s;
limit_req_status 429;   
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=connlimit:100m;
limit_conn_status 429;

### STATUS HTTP ### 
map $status $status_text {
    400 'Bad Request';
    401 'Unauthorized';
    402 'Payment Required';
    403 'Forbidden';
    404 'Not Found';
    405 'Method Not Allowed';
    406 'Not Acceptable';
    407 'Proxy Authentication Required';
    408 'Request Timeout';
    409 'Conflict';
    410 'Gone';
    411 'Length Required';
    412 'Precondition Failed';
    413 'Payload Too Large';
    414 'URI Too Long';
    415 'Unsupported Media Type';
    416 'Range Not Satisfiable';
    417 'Expectation Failed';
    418 'I\'m a teapot';
    421 'Misdirected Request';
    422 'Unprocessable Entity';
    423 'Locked';
    424 'Failed Dependency';
    425 'Too Early';
    426 'Upgrade Required';
    428 'Precondition Required';
    429 'Too Many Requests';
    431 'Request Header Fields Too Large';
    451 'Unavailable For Legal Reasons';
    500 'Internal Server Error';
    501 'Not Implemented';
    502 'Bad Gateway';
    503 'Service Unavailable';
    504 'Gateway Timeout';
    505 'HTTP Version Not Supported';
    506 'Variant Also Negotiates';
    507 'Insufficient Storage';
    508 'Loop Detected';
    510 'Not Extended';
    511 'Network Authentication Required';
    default 'Something is wrong';
}

### Virtual Host Configs ###
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Your question indicates that you are changing the `map_hash_` values, but there are also [`variables_hash_` values](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables_hash_bucket_size) as indicated by the warning message.

Comment: in the warning message `variables_hash_bucket` is a generic value. I don't use variables_hash_bucket in my setup. Only `map_hash_max_size`, `map_hash_bucket_size`, `server_names_hash_bucket_size` and `types_hash_max_size`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "generic value". In addition to the map, server_names, and types hash, Nginx uses a variables hash. The warning is telling you that the default size for the variables hash is too small. The default size is `variables_hash_bucket_size 64` and `variables_hash_max_size 1024`. You need to add statements to your configuration to make one or both of these values larger.

Comment: Yes, the message is explicit and I have already modified the values by multiplying them by two but it does not work. I tried several combinations. I modified the values of the variables `type_`, `server_name_`, `map_`, `client_`.

Comment: I also deactivate each variable one by one to try to identify the one that is causing the problem, but no matter which variable is activated, the warning message appears.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was:

`/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
http {
    ...
    types_hash_bucket_size 128;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think this might be some kind of bug in Nginx. According to documentation we should increase `types_hash_max_size` but `types_hash_bucket_size` should stay fixed according to CPU's cache line size, see https://nginx.org/en/docs/hash.html
For me if I check `/proc/cpuinfo` I see there `cache_alignment: 64`

and for me this does remove warning about `could not build optimal types_hash`


    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    types_hash_bucket_size 64;

Comment: But it doesn't fix warning about `could not build optimal proxy_headers_hash`, no matter how big `proxy_headers_hash_max_size` I make. But increasing `proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size` indeed fixes warning

```
    proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
    proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
```

This doesn't make sense because `proxy_headers_hash_max_size 65536` is so much larger.